# Changing certificate on each outgoing call with Feign

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, feign

I have a case were I need to have different certificates for each outgoing call I make with Netflix Feign.

```
return Feign.builder()
      .requestInterceptor(new MarathonHeadersInterceptor())
      .errorDecoder(new NetsErrorDecoder())
      .logger(new Logger.ErrorLogger())
      .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
      .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
      .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
      .target(X.class, endpoint);
```

Comment: What is your question? Where does your current code fail?

Comment: Corrected typos, but the quality of the question is still low :/